# Hot to remove :nth-child elements, with loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
    $(".element:nth-child(i)").hide();
    console.log($(".element:nth-child(i)"));
}
```

But I have an error in my console "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child", what is wrong? How to remove my elements from the page with loop?

Comment: What is that `.element(i)` selector meant to be? I can't see any reference to that in the documentation?

Comment: @Phil Awww, thanks, it was a mistake. I mean :nth-child(i).

Comment: probably a simpler way to do this if you show html sample structure. Also what is `data`? if it is array the loop is incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery will interpret this literally: `".element:nth-child(i)"`

You should use it like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < data; i++) {
    $(".element:nth-child("+ i +")").hide();
    console.log( $(".element:nth-child("+ i +")") );
}
```

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived
>   from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning
>   that the counting starts at 1. For other selector expressions such as
>   :eq() or :even jQuery follows JavaScript's "0-indexed" counting. Given
>   a single  containing two
>
> s, $( "li:nth-child(1)" ) selects the
>   first
>
> while  $( "li:eq(1)" ) selects the second.

nth-element doc: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: `nth-child` is not zero based and still concatenation missing in log version

Comment: naah `data` is probably an `.length` so iteration should probably be zero based.  `i + 1` or `i <= data`

Comment: Added the relevant doc quote to the answer.

Comment: @Raphael but your edit introduce an other bug : you are missing the last element.